# php.ini extensions XAMPP

Tags: php, windows, xampp

I am trying to set up XAMPP 1.7.7 in my windows 7 64bits.
I need some extensions that were not coming in the XAMPP package so I downloaded them from the internet, place them in the xampp/php/ext folder and uncomented the correspondent lines in the php.ini.

But I continuosly get the following warning:

*PHP Startup: mcrypt: Unable to initialize module Module compiled with build ID=API20090626, TS,VC6 PHP compiled with build ID=API20090626, TS,VC9 These options need to match*

That makes apache shut down everytime. What can I do?  I have no idea where to "attack" the problem.

Thank you very much in advance,
Javier.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you find VC9 TS (VC9 = Compiler Version [6 or 9], TS = Thread Safe) versions of the PECLs you need [here](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/). Note that VC9 and TS must match, otherwise it won't work. If you can't find a matching binary on that site, you'll either have to compile it yourself, (google for a possible binary), or ask around if someone can do it for you.

[Compiling PECL extension on Windows](http://fishtrap.co.uk/blog/2010/10/27/compiling-pecl-extensions-on-windows-timezonedb/) might help…

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response. There aren't the extensions that I am looking for in the link. How could I compile it by myself? What else could I try to do?

Comment: [Compiling PECL extension on Windows](http://fishtrap.co.uk/blog/2010/10/27/compiling-pecl-extensions-on-windows-timezonedb/) might help

Comment: At the end what I did was to take an older version of XAMPP, concretely to the 1.7.3, and now it is working.